# complex number substitution within a function

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to make a simple substitution:

$a \in C$  and    $0<|a|<1$

> $f_{a}(z)=\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}$
>
> Demonstrate that if |z|=1 then |$f_a(z)|=1$ .

I used.  $z=|z|e^{I\theta}$  but that did not get me anywhere.

Comment: Note that $$|z|=1\implies \frac1{z}=\overline{z}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac{z-a}{1-\overline az}=\frac{z-a}{\overline zz-\overline az}=\frac{z-a}{\overline z-\overline a}\cdot\frac1z.$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Realise the denominator multiplying by $$\frac{1-a\bar z}{1-a\bar z}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I did not notice that $|z-a|=|\bar z-\bar a|$ which leads to the answer.